# MATLAB: Remove everything after the final blank in a character array

Tags: matlab, char

How can I remove all characters after the final blank in a character array?

Input:

```
ch = {'Test1 Index'; 'Test 2 Index'; 'Test 3 4 Curncy'}
```

Expected Output:

```
ch = {'Test1'; 'Test 2'; 'Test 3 4'}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your example it seems that you want to remove all characters after the final blank, *and remove that final blank too*.

You can use [`regexrep`](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/regexprep.html) as follows:

```
result = regexprep(ch, '\s\S*$', '');
```

The regular expression `'\s\S*$'` matches a blank (`\s`) followed by zero or more non-blanks (`\S*`) up to the end of the string (`$`). The matched substring is replaced by the empty string (`''`).

Comment: Could you please elaborate on why the regular expression only matches from the last space and not from any (practically the first) space?

Comment: @NickyMattsson Because it matches a blank followed by zero or more _non-blanks_ until the end of the string. If there are several blanks, the first would not be followed by non-blanks only